# Failing at passing the title to android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

This is called from a button in my app. It works great except for passing of the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void addCalendarClicked(int position)
    {             
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", MyStringUtils.dateFromRawTimestamp(_routes[position].getDepartureDateTime()).getTime());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", MyStringUtils.dateFromRawTimestamp(_routes[position].getArrivalDateTime()).getTime());
       intent.putExtra("title", "hello first alarm");

        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: how does the code look like where you retrieve the title

Comment: i don't understand your question?

Comment: the title will be retrieven automatically by android calender

Comment: how does the calendar retrieve the title from the bundle like bundle.getString ("title") or how do you do that

Comment: set title automatically? does it? any reference link...

Comment: i am trying to do the same as written his: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents

Comment: What are you trying to do here? you edit a existing calendar event or adding a new one?

Comment: i add new one to my list of calendar alerts

Answer (score 1):

In your code you not appending the eventID to the URI... How does it know which one to edit..

```
long eventID = 208;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT) 
    .setData(uri) 
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My New Title"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

### Update :

You can try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI) // `content://com.android.calendar/events`
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i got an error on "Events.", eclipse can not found anything called Events. No imports provided for me?

Comment: What is your android version? Its available in API 14.

Comment: error: Events cannot be resolved to a variable,
i use level 11

Comment: can i use other params (other than Events.CONTENT_URI) that will work for Android3.0?

Comment: Shouldn't it be ACTION_INSERT if you are adding an event?

Comment: When i changed ACTIO_EDIT to ACTION_INSERT i got this exception:
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/event (has extras) }

Comment: the URI should be `content://com.android.calendar/events`

Comment: See this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void setRemindar(String titleD,String msgD,final String Title ,final String Description,final String day ,final String month,final String year){

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
                Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(AlAujairyHoneycombActivity.this) + "events");
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                long startMillis = 0; 
                long endMillis = 0; 
                Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                beginTime.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day), 9, 0);
                startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
                Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                endTime.set(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day), 10, 0);
                endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
                // event insert
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("calendar_id", 1);
                values.put("title", Title);
                values.put("allDay", 0);
                values.put("dtstart", startMillis ); // event starts at 11 minutes from now
                values.put("dtend", endMillis); // ends 60 minutes from now
                values.put("description", Description);
                values.put("visibility", 0);
                values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
                // reminder insert
                Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(AlAujairyHoneycombActivity.this) + "reminders");
                values = new ContentValues();
                values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
                values.put( "method", 1 );
                values.put( "minutes", 10 );
                cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );

    }
    private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {
        String calendarUriBase = null;
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor = null;
        try {
            managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
        } else {
            calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
            try {
                managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (managedCursor != null) {
                calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
            }
        }
        return calendarUriBase;
    }
```

In  Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: it work but it is not what i want. I don't want to build another dialog. I want to use the default dialog off calendar

Comment: i got an exception?
E/AndroidRuntime(10497): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL nullevents
the error is in that line: Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

Comment: Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(yourActivity.this) + "events");